# Variable sized UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have somewhat of an odd problem. I've already got a UITableView setup with custom heights for my table cells. The problem comes in when the content is loaded in the background for the cells. I need the cells to load asap, but theres a big image for each cell, that may take some time to load (from the network or flash), so the load is started in the background when the cell is first loaded. This means that the height for the cell is initially wrong, and needs to be updated later with a minimum of glitching. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't always want to update the table, or the image, and can cause some excess scrolling.

It's also incredibly slow. I have some optimizations I need to do to make it a bit less slow (make smaller copies of the main image, and cache the height for the cells temporarily).

I've tried all sorts of things. I make sure the table is told to update in the main thread, I've tried a bare set of beginUpdates/endUpdates, reloadRows/reloadSections (table is in grouped mode, with one row per section). I have yet to get the table to update properly once the image has finished loading.

If anyone has some insight into how to get this to work as smoothly as possible I'd appreciate it.

Comment: So I've solved my problems. Basically I had to move the image loading code from the cell, to the view controller(s), and fix a couple stupid bugs. Also spent some time to optimize things, and its a lot smoother now.

Answer (score 1):

The place to go is your `heightForRowAtIndex:` method. It needs to know if the image exists or not and return a value accordingly. Every time each row finishes loading it's image, you should call reloadRows~ method like this:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:y]];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

I'm not entirely sure if this will cause some heavy scrolling on your tableView, but it's an option.

Another option is to update in chunks. Say every 5-10 images (depending on how many you have) that get loaded reload their respective rows with that same method.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. I'm having a bit of an issue with that currently as that totally reloads the cell, which re-calls the image fetching code. Is it even guaranteed that the same UITableViewCell is reused for the reloaded cell? I'm trying to find a good way to break the loop, but if it isn't the same cell object, theres pretty much no way to properly break it.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to re-use the same cell, it will use the last one that was queued. You could create some kind of handler (or do it in the parent controller of your tableView) that handles download of the images and communicates to your rows so that it doesn't try to re-load an image that was loaded / is being loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to do something like that it seems. Take a bit of wrangling I think.

Comment: Ok, so I've updated to do something like that, it mostly works, but the last few cells don't want to update properly. Probably some bug of mine I need to find. but sheesh the UITableView is so annoying.